# Angular console to view

Tags: angular

I want to display console data on my localhost whenever a button is clicked. How would I display such data on my website? When I click the button, I see the data in the console and all I need now is for the actual data to be visualized in a grid view or similar.

Comment: What you are asking is not clear at all. Where are the data coming from? What did you try so far? What is blocking you?

Comment: Not clear. Could you elaborate more on that?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are displaying this data with a `console.log` that triggers from a `(click)` event on a button.

You need to take whatever data you are generating with this click, save it in a variable like

component.ts

```
let variableToDisplay = null;
const onClickFunction = () => {
   variableToDisplay = 'hello';
}
```

component.html

```
<div>
    {{variableToDisplay}}
</div>
```

Hope that helps. Additionally, really read the Angular documentation and go through a couple tutorials, it will help.